# Classify dataframe rows based on probabibility - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. 
First one is related to users and looks like this:

```
user_id    city_id
  0           a
  1           a
  2           b
  3           a
  4           c
.. and so on
```

Second one gives information how many percent of each city belongs to each district, something like this:

```
 city_id     district_id    probability
    a             a1           0.01
    a             a2           0.02
    a             a3           0.02
    a             a4           0.56
    a             a5           0.39
    b             b1           0.63
    b             b2           0.07
    b             b3           0.30
 and so on..
```

I need to organize users based on this probability to which district of their city they belong. So (for example) that I get approximatelly 56% that users that live in city a are from district a4 and so on. Basically final df would have rows related to the `user_id, city_id and district_id`.

My first clue was to give each user a random number and to compare with the probability.

My second idea was to group by rows by city_id, to look up at the second table and select (give value to the third column) by probability. So basically for the city a, that means that I will select 56% rows in the group and give it district value a4 and so on.
But I am not sure that mathematically is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df1` and `df2` are your two dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
def get_district(city):
    dlist = list(df2.loc[df2['city_id']==city, 'district_id']) #get list of districts
    p = list(df2.loc[df2['city_id']==city, 'probability']) #get corresponding odds
    return np.random.choice(dlist, p=p) #give weighed random choice from list
```

And apply this:

```
df['district_id'] = df.city_id.apply(get_district)
```

After @JoeCondron's helpful comments, another method:

```
def get_city_district(city,df1,df2):
    l = len(df1[df1.city_id==city])
    d = df2[df2['city_id']==city]
    ds, p = list(d['district_id']),list(d['probability'])
    df1.loc[df1.city_id==city,'district_id'] = np.random.choice(ds, size=l,p=p)
    return df1

def f(df1,df2):
    df1['district_id'] = None
    for i in set(df1.city_id):
        df1 = get_city_district(i,df1,df2)

    return df1
```

Much faster when tested, but only with a few cities.

Comment: This will call `get_district` for every single row in `df` which will in turn slice `df2` each time unnecessarily. We only need to get the weightings for each unique city once. Also, you are generating the same Boolean key twice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing the following:

```
for city in city_info.city_id.unique():
    probs = city_info[city_info.city_id == city]
    in_city = users.city_id == city
    n_citizens = in_city.sum()
    n_districts = len(probs)
    district = np.random.choice(range(n_district), n_citizens, p=probs) + 1 # adding one as range is base 0
    users.loc[in_city, 'district_id'] = city + pd.Series(district).astype(str)
```